# How can I optimize my KnockoutJS pureComputed function?

Tags: javascript, performance, knockout.js

I'm starting to notice poor performance in my little game as I'm adding more KO stuff to it.

I have a RessourcesVM which contain AllRessources as an observableArray. This store **MainRessource** object containing the name, total quantity, total capacity, a list of all **Building** object that is used to store this ressource.

Example: Rock and Wood have both the same Stockpile **Building** object in their "StorageBuilding". This Ressource object is stored in RessourcesVM's AllRessources observableArray.

I'm trying to create a little HUB that display the number of ressources.

In my **MainRessource** object I have this pureComputed function to calculate, I decided the parse the whole object here so you get a better understanding of the object:

```
function MainRessource(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.Name = data.Name;
  self.IconCss = data.IconCss;

  //Incremented by the BuildingVM once the building's construction is completed
  self.TotalQte = ko.observable(isNaN(data.TotalQte) ? 0 : data.TotalQte);
  self.TotalCapacity = ko.observable(isNaN(data.TotalCapacity) ? 0 : data.TotalCapacity);


  self.ProductionRate = ko.observable(isNaN(data.ProductionRate) ? 0 : data.ProductionRate);
  self.getProductionRatePerSecond = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var p = Game.app.cf.refreshEvery/self.ProductionRate();
    if(p > 0 && p != 'Infinity')
      return p;
    return 0;
  });

  if(data.StoredIn) { //TODO implement this properly
    self.StoredIn = data.StoredIn;
  } else {
    console.log("Warning: Ressource with name "+self.Name+" doesn't appear to have a StoredIn set.");
  }
  self.StorageBuildings = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.ProductionBuildings = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.OccupyingSpace = ko.observable(data.OccupyingSpace);


    self.getMaxCapacity = ko.pureComputed(function() {

      if(self.Name == "Energy") {
        //Energy is not "stored" in any buildings, return direct value
        var v = Math.floor(self.TotalCapacity());

      } else if(self.Name == "Wood") {
        //To calculate max wood capacity,, remove the space Rock occupies
        var r = Game.app.Ressources.AllRessources()[2];
        r = (r.TotalQte() / r.OccupyingSpace());

        var v = Math.floor((self.TotalCapacity()-r)/self.OccupyingSpace());

      } else if(self.Name == "Rock") {
        //To calculate max wood capacity,, remove the space Wood occupies
        var w = Game.app.Ressources.AllRessources()[1];
        w = (w.TotalQte() / w.OccupyingSpace());

        var v = Math.floor((self.TotalCapacity()-w)/self.OccupyingSpace());

      } else if(self.StoredIn == "FoodStorage") {
        var startWith = self.TotalCapacity(); //Total food capacity
        //For each Ressource that is stored in FoodStorage building type, remove the occupying space of that ressource
        for(var l = Game.app.Ressources.AllRessources.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            //Skip the ressource we are calculating for
            if(Game.app.Ressources.AllRessources.StoredIn == 'FoodStorage' && Game.app.Ressources.AllRessources.Name != self.Name) {
              var w = Game.app.Ressources.AllRessources()[i];
              startWith -= (w.TotalQte() / w.OccupyingSpace());
            }
          }

          var v = Math.floor(startWith/self.OccupyingSpace());
      }

      if(isNaN(v) || v <= 0)
        return 0;

      return v;
    });

}
```

The HTML code for the HUB looks like this:

```
<!-- ko with: Ressources -->
  <!-- ko foreach: AllRessources -->
  <div class="hub" >
    <i data-bind="css: IconCss"></i>
    <span data-bind="text: Math.floor(TotalQte())"></span>/<span data-bind="text: getMaxCapacity()"></span>
    (<span data-bind="text: getProductionRatePerSecond()"></span>) <span data-bind="meter: {value: TotalQte, max: TotalCapacity }" class="meter-sm"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

I know the pureComputed function is a little mess for now, I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do this.

Should I move the getMaxCapacity function in the RessourcesVM? Would this give me some performance benefits?

More infos about the logic:
You can have multiple stockpiles, stockpiles stores Wood and Rock. Rock use 2 spaces, wood use 1 (That's why there is this "OccupyingSpace thing in the previous code)
You can have multiple Granaries, Granaries stores Apple and Bread.

I need to know how many Apples there is across all Granaries and the combined capacity of all granaries.

Thanks for your help

**edit** changed Ressource to MainRessource in my explanation to reflect the real object's name provided in the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact performance issues are, but you could try extending the computed to `.extend({ deferred: true })`. This ensures your computed is only re-evaluated once when you're modifying its dependencies consecutively. (e.g. pushing `n` times to `AllResources` results in `1` computation)

Comment: Thanks, I was making sure that my pureComputed was "normal", never used KO before I though this function was too huge. But yea I already set `ko.options.deferUpdates = false; ko.options.rateLimit = 25;` ;) thx

Comment: I still think you can improve the computed method, but I don't think you'll have to worry too much about performance. Main point of improvement: since `Name` isn't observable, I'd suggest using a IIFE to make sure the main `if` statement only executes once.

Comment: Good point, thank you so much!