# How to avoid redrawing entire tab every time in KnockoutJS?

Tags: performance, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, redraw

In this very basic example using Bootstrap Tabs, every time I click on a tab, KnockoutJS redraw the entire tab, is there a way to "save" the state of the tab so next time I click on Messages, KO doesn't have to redraw the entire thing?

It takes ~100ms to draw. (According to Chromium profiler), fps drops to 1fps. It makes the whole thing very unresponsive.

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab_storage" data-bind="with: BuildingsVM">

    <h2 data-bind="i18next: 'AllOurStorage'"></h2>
    <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: buildingsByType['RawStorage']">
      <div data-bind="template: { name: 'tpl_building' }"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: buildingsByType['RefinedStorage']">
      <div data-bind="template: { name: 'tpl_building' }"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages" data-bind="messages">
      <div data-bind="foreach: message">
        <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to keep the state of the DOM so KO doesn't have to redraw the entire tab every time I click on it? (Or an alternative solution)

I'm using the following ko options to avoid unnecessary updates when I array.push(a_lot_of_things):

```
ko.options.deferUpdates = true;
ko.options.rateLimit = 25;
```

EDIT:
Tabs are switched using Bootstrap JS library.

```
 $("#MenuTab").on('click','a', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = $(this).attr('href');
   $(this).tab("show");
 });
```

Template for a building 'card':

```
<script type="text/html" id="tpl_building">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="card card-raised">
      <div class="card-header"><h3 data-bind="text: buildingName"></h3> </div>
      <div class="card-content">

        <div class="row" data-bind="if: (buildingType == 'RawStorage' || buildingType == 'RefinedStorage')">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            Usage: <span data-bind="text: getOccupyingSpace"></span> / <span data-bind="text: TotalCapacity"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <span data-bind="meter: {value: getOccupyingSpace, max: TotalCapacity}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
        <!-- ko foreach: Ressources -->
        <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="if: $parent.TotalCapacity">
          <span data-bind="text: Name"></span> <span data-bind="text: Qte"></span> (<span class="small" data-bind="text: getOccupyingSpace"></span>)
          <!-- ko if: ProductionRate() -->
          <span data-bind="text: ProductionRate()"></span>/s
          <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="if: ProductionRate">
          <span data-bind="text: Name"></span> <span data-bind="text: getProductionRatePerSecond()"></span>/s (1 every <span data-bind="text: ProductionRate()/1000"></span> sec)
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <!-- ko if: initialConstructionGoing -->
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle icon-gradient-warning" class="ko-popover"
  data-bind="popover: initialConstructionGoing, popoverOptions: { title: i18nextko.t('UnderConstruction_potitle') }" ></i>
  <span data-bind="i18next: 'UnderConstruction'"></span> <span data-bind="text: getBuildProgress"></span>
  <span data-bind="meter: {p: getBuildProgress, onComplete: 'remove'}"></span>
  <span data-bind="WorkersAssigned().length"></span>/<span data-bind="WorkersBuild"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Custom binding for 'meter' (A progress bar):

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.meter = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
          // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
          // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
          var progress = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

          if(progress.value) {
            var value = ko.unwrap(progress.value);
            var max = ko.unwrap(progress.max);

            if(value === 0 && max === 0) {
              var percentage = 0;
            } else {
              var percentage = (value/max)*100;
            }
          } else {
            var percentage = ko.unwrap(progress.p);
          }




          $progress_tpl = $('<div class="meter"><span style="width: '+percentage+'%"></span></div>');
          if(progress.onComplete) {
            $progress_tpl.attr('data-oncomplete', progress.onComplete);
          }
          $(element).append($progress_tpl);


      },
      update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
          // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
          // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
          // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
          var progress = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
          if(progress.value) {
            var value = ko.unwrap(progress.value);
            var max = ko.unwrap(progress.max);
            var percentage = (value/max)*100;

          } else {
            var percentage = ko.unwrap(progress.p);

          }

          $(element).find('.meter span').stop().animate({'width': percentage+'%'}, (bindingContext.$root.cf.refreshEvery), 'swing', function() {
            if(percentage >= 100) {
              if($(element).find(".meter").attr('data-oncomplete') == 'remove') {
                $(element).hide(300, function() {
                  $(element).remove();
                  ko.cleanNode(element);

                });
              } else if($(element).find(".meter").attr('data-oncomplete') == 'reset') {
                $(element).hide(300, function() {
                  $(element).remove();
                });
              } else {

              }

            }
          });


      }
  };
```

my KO main VM:

```
var mainVM = {
    Ressources: new RessourcesVM(),
    Buildings: new BuildingsVM(),
    cf: {
      ...
    }
}
```

Also modified original tab-content code to reflect the real code (using templates).

I would've made a JSfiddle but for some obscure reasons, it doesn't seem to work properly (new router firmware might be the issue, blocking CDN)à

For a better understanding cotext-wise, you can have a look at my other question: [How can I optimize my KnockoutJS pureComputed function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077934/how-can-i-optimize-my-knockoutjs-purecomputed-function)

Looking at the DOM tree in the console, all the elements are still present, even if the tab is not active - maybe something else make the delay.

Comment: Are you using a custom binding? How are you switching which tab is active?

Comment: Oops haha yea it could help, updated the question.

Comment: Wow, after investigating all calls made in the Profiler, it seems that a border-image took way too much time to rasterize. After removing that class property, chromium seems to render faster and doesn't have a 200ms display time (only 40ms avg.) - didn't know CSS could impact performance that much!